# SSL certificate mismatches not using domain ssl but plesk default ssl certificate

Tags: linux, ssl, plesk

Since last night, somehow there is something wrong with the SSL certificates.

https://mail.domainfromclient.com was working fine, but now the domain try's to load the default server certificate plesk.ourdomain.com but we have no clue what is going on and why this is happenings.

Also when we add a new domain to plesk newdomain.com without configuring SSL/let's encrypt certificate when we load http in the browser it redirects it to the ssl but there is no ssl connected to the domain so i's tries to load the default certificate of the plesk server plesk.ourdomain.com but since this is not the domain there is a certificate issue

Does anyone had this issue using plesk?

We are running
AlmaLinux 8.6 (Sky Tiger)
Plesk Obsidian
Version 18.0.45